# Java calling methods non/static and private/public

Tags: java, call

I just had some method calling scenarios I was unsure of, and was hoping someone could help clear some up for me.

a) If I was in the `SalesMethod` class and I wanted to call the sales method from the region method how would I do that? (`private` method calling `public` method)

b) What about sales calling purchase? (`public` calling `public` from within same class)

c)If I was in `SalesMethod`, what would be a way to call the `futureSales` method?  Would I have to create an instance for it since it's non static?

Thanks in advance.

```java
public class SalesMethod
{
  public static double sales ()
  {
    code
  }
  private static void region ()
  {
    code
  }
  public static double purchase ()
  {
    code
  }
  public void futureSales ()
  {
    code
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you think? Please try to demonstrate minimal understanding.

Comment: a)  have you tried `double d = sales()`

Comment: b)  have you tried `double d = purchase()`

Comment: for a and b would declaring a variable, then catching it suffice?

Comment: first, there are no methods declared for the SalesMethod class.  go here and start reading: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Comment: c) yes, you'll have to create an instance, but if you're creating a new instance **only** to `futureSales', you might as well make `futureSales` static in the first place

Comment: you would have to refresh a bit your Java: http://www.learnjavaonline.org/en/Functions

Comment: Please go through a [java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html)

Comment: Public and private apply for other classes trying to access the "SalesMethod" class by instantiating it and accessing its members using dot operators. From with the "SalesMethod" class they mean nothing.

Answer (score 1):

a) private method calling public method is ok since public mean "visible from everywhere".

```
 public static double region()
 {
       sales();
 }
```

b) public method calling public method is ok for the same reason.

b') public method calling private method is ok if the private method is in the same class than the public one.

c) to call a non-static method, you have to create an instance since you call it "on" an object. You can't call it from a static method the way you do in the example above.

static means "relative to a class"
non-static is relative to an object, you can see that as an action performed by the object.

Answer (score 0):

> If I was in the SalesMethod class and I wanted to call the sales method from the region method how would I do that? (private method calling public method)

They are both static, so you can call them everytime you need to.

```
sales();
// Or
SalesMethod.sales();
```

---

> What about sales calling purchase? (public calling public from within same class)

They are both static, so you can call them everytime you need to.

```
purchase();
// Or
SalesMethod.purchase();
```

---

> If I was in SalesMethod, what would be a way to call the futureSales method? Would I have to create an instance for it since it's non static?

Yes.

```
SalesMethod instance = new SalesMethod();
instance.futureSales();
```